# Pandas weighted average for panel (T*N) data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, average

I wanted to calculate yearly weighted average for some daily observations. Accordingly, I need to first calculate weighted average for each day and then find regular (equally weighted) mean across all days in a year (a picture of data and desired output is below.)

Here is my not-working code snippet:

```py
def ave_annual(s):
    return s.groupby(s.index.year).mean()


wav = lambda x: np.average(x['premium'], weights=x.tna)

df.groupby('date').apply(wav).pipe(ave_annual)
```

the first aggregation (at date (day) level) returns all `NaN`.

I managed to calculate the average in an step-by-step and slow approach:

```py
master_2 = (master_1.assign(tna_sum =  master_1.groupby('date')
.tna.transform('sum'))[lambda x: x['tna_sum'] > 0 ]

res_premium = master_2.groupby(
'date')['prem_wieghted2'].sum().pipe(ave_annual)
```

I was wondering (1) what wrong  it is that I receive `NaN`s and (2) how I may use the this approach (`np.average`) for calculating the averages for two variables.

Data:

```html
date ticker premium spread tna
3/4/2013 x -0.69 0.1261 7.2329
3/4/2013 y 0.096 0.296 49.496
3/4/2013 x 0.142 0.4352 167.5251
3/6/2013 x -0.69 0.1261 7.2329
3/6/2013 z 0.096 0.296 49.496
3/6/2013 y 0.084 0.21 110
3/4/2019 x NaN 0.1392 16.431
3/4/2019 y NaN NaN 100.6774
```

[image]

Comment: you should build a minimal sample datas if you want help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following ecortazar's suggestion and data sample, I think the snippet below is a workaround.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': np.random.rand(1000), 
                   'weight_source': np.random.rand(1000)},
                  index=pd.date_range(start="2010/01/01", periods=1000, freq='D'))
def ave_annual(s):
    return s.groupby(s.index.year).mean()


(df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: (x['data'] * x['weight_source']
.div(x['weight_source'].sum())).sum())
.pipe(ave_annual))
```

results:

```
    2010    0.535598
    2011    0.493956
    2012    0.517653
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the operation you are looking for is `groupby(...).transform(...)`.

Your example is hard to follow. Here is a simpler example: In this case I'm calculating the annual weights from the column *weight_source* and applying it to the *data* column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': np.random.rand(1000), 
                   'weight_source': np.random.rand(1000)},
                  index=pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2010, 1, 1), periods=1000, freq='D'))

year_sum = df['weight_source'].groupby(df.index.year).transform('sum')

weights = df['weight_source'] / year_sum

weights * df['data']
```